# 144Hz monitor with freesync noise on 40m

Tags: hf, rfi

When I tune on 40 m (7.074 MHz USB as test frequency for there's FT8) and turn on my PC with a monitor that's 144 Hz refresh rate and has freesync on, it starts to make noise and makes signals almost impossible to listen.

Measuring the audio output with a simple audio spectrum analyzer on the pc, the noise is around 1.5 kHz and whenever I change the monitor's refresh rate (59, 60, 100 and 120 Hz are the other possible options) the noise changes frequency (729-772 Hz) and is lower, and when I turn off freesync on the monitor the noise ceases.

I noticed that if I put my hand touching or almost touching the screen, the noise becomes a bit louder and so does the audio analyzer on the specified frequencies.

How can this noise be eliminated?

Comment: ... so, turn of FreeSync. Unless you really need to watch movies or play games that are at a slightly different frame rate than your screen, it has no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: @MarcusMüller please make your comment an answer.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @rclocher3 to which question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller to this one.

Comment: The problem is that this is a description of a situation, not really a question. Is the question "how do I fix *this*?", is it "What's the reason for this?", is it "How does one go about investigating these things?"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fixed that for you. :-) You were right, it really didn't look like a question. However, it's sort of a given that the boxes at the top are questions. [Might be good for us all to review these commenting rules](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds very much to me like you should turn off freesync, and only turn it on when you actually need it (while playing games, presumably), at which point you probably won't be playing radio anyway - so it will have little effect.

Comment: My question was more in the way of understanding the nature of that noise and if it was possible at all to remove it, but for now I think this is the only working approach I can have.